# Help solving system of linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

In the process of running through an algorithm, I have derived the following systems of equations:

i) $1/3 + 1/3x_1 + 1/3 x_6 = x_5$

ii) $1/2 + 1/4 x_6 = x_1$

iii) $1/2 + 1/2 x_5 = x_6$

I've tried adding i and ii together, but it doesn't help isolate any of the unknowns? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The equations have already been simplified since the other variables had the values:

$x_0 = x_2 = 0 $

$x_3 = x_4 = x_7 = 1$

Comment: Some of the others are equal to 0 and some 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we ca write
$$1+x_1+x_6=3x_5$$
$$2+x_6=4x_1$$
$$1+x_5=2x_6$$
with $x_5=2x_6-1$ we get
$$x_1-5x_6=-4$$
and with $$x_6=4x_1-2$$ we obtain
$$x_1-5(4x_1-2)=-4$$ thus we get $$x_1=\frac{14}{19}$$
from here we can proceed.